# Laravel http (curl) throws RequestException while creating the response

Tags: laravel, http, guzzle

I have a simple curl API request in a project that is based on Laravel 9 by using XAMPP. I use the `Http::withHeaders(array("key" => "value))->post("api-url")` to call the API (see [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests)).

> `Http::withOptions(['debug' => fopen('php://stderr', 'w')])->withHeaders($header)->get($url)`

The handling is to get a JSON from an external API. The API is valid (https://api.clearstream.com/) and I am authenticated via a registered API key. (Other API-Endpoints are working fine)

The problem I have is that I get the following deatiled Laravel error:
[Laravel - DetailedCodeOfFail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIvKR.png)

When I use the http option "debug" I get the following error:

> [object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): "default-src 'self';
> script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src-elem
> 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self'
> 'unsafe-inline'; style-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src
> 'self'; frame-src 'self'; worker-src 'self'; connect-src 'self';
> manifest-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self';
> form-action 'self' ; object-src 'none'; block-all-mixed-content;" is
> not valid header value at
> \vendor\guzzlehttp\psr7\src\MessageTrait.php:263)
>
> \vendor\guzzlehttp\psr7\src\MessageTrait.php(209):
> GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response->assertValue('default-src 'se...')
>
> [internal function]:
> GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response->GuzzleHttp\Psr7\{closure}('default-src
> 'se...')

Any idea why the response fails?

- all versions are nearly up to date

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) - edit your question and show the (relevant) part of the error message(s).  The Laravel `Request` docs that you link to are about handling *incoming* requests to your Laravel application, but AFAICT your qeustion is about making an *outgoing* request to a remote API?  Can you clarify?

Comment: "*When I use the http option "debug"...*" - how, where?  Show us your code.  Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You can get this error when the third-party api you are consuming sends header values that don't meet guzzlehttp/psr7's [regex check](https://github.com/guzzle/psr7/blob/bc778a3f18eb0f8423ea707cd0bdf375c696ec81/src/MessageTrait.php#L259-L264).  This check was added to the psr7 library back in 2022-03-20 but will cause more headaches for developers now that guzzlehttp/guzzle [includes the latest psr7](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/commit/1dd98b0564cb3f6bd16ce683cb755f94c10fbd82#diff-d2ab9925cad7eac58e0ff4cc0d251a937ecf49e4b6bf57f8b95aab76648a9d34) (2022-06-20).

There is a [bug report](https://github.com/guzzle/psr7/issues/524) for this issue.